# How to retrieve value from IDataReader that have multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcommand, idatareader

I've been trying to get values from `IDataReader` recently an have been unable to get data from the second table I queried. Can someone please help me find a way to get them. Here is what i have so far:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT name, value from Company.dbo.A;SELECT sum(value) from Company.dbo.A  ", connection))
{
    command.Notification = null;

    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                      .Select(x => new LocationInfo()
                        {
                            Names = x.GetString(0),
                            Values = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(1), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                            ValuesDouble=x.GetDouble(1),
                            SumVol=x.GetDouble(2)//this line does not work(index out of bounds error)

                      }).ToList();
}
```

Hence how do you get the second SQL command which is `SUM(value) into SumVol` that I have created the `public double SumVol { get; set; }` for?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`reader.NextResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the reader to output the 2nd result set. You will likely need to do it in two passes or restructure your query to do it in a single result set.

here is a query that gives you the sum per unique name

```
SELECT name, value, SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY name) from Company.dbo.A;
```

here is a one that uses a subquery to get the total sum to be printed on each line

```
SELECT name, value, (SELECT sum(value) from Company.dbo.A) from Company.dbo.A;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there any way to get the value from two sqlcommands?    because my query is much more complicated than that. thank you in advance

Comment: I told you in my frst paragraph, use `reader.NextResult()` to switch to the 2nd result set then update the list's values before you return the result.

Comment: I still dont understand how I can use reader.NextResult(). Do i have to make 2 using(reader) ?, where do i put the reader.NextResult()?. Sorry for asking too much but can you give me the example in the use of the reader.NextResult() in the above context. Thank you for your attention btw :)